# Cython: Compile a Standalone Static Executable

Tags: python, c++, c, cython, static-linking

I'm trying to compile an executable (ELF file) that does not use a dynamic loader.
I used `Cython` to compile Python to C:

```
cython3 -3 test.py --embed
```

Then

```
gcc test.c -otest $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3)
```

to compile C generated file.

Now I'd like to compile `test.c` in a static executable.
Usually I use `-static` flag, but here it return `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

How can I do?

**EDIT 1:** *Not the full messge becouse body is limited to 30000 chars*

*a long list of warnings and errors like these*:

```
...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x430): undefined reference to `XML_SetStartCdataSectionHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x458): undefined reference to `XML_SetEndCdataSectionHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x480): undefined reference to `XML_SetDefaultHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x4a8): undefined reference to `XML_SetDefaultHandlerExpand'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x4d0): undefined reference to `XML_SetNotStandaloneHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x4f8): undefined reference to `XML_SetExternalEntityRefHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x520): undefined reference to `XML_SetStartDoctypeDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x548): undefined reference to `XML_SetEndDoctypeDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x570): undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x598): undefined reference to `XML_SetXmlDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x5c0): undefined reference to `XML_SetElementDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x5e8): undefined reference to `XML_SetAttlistDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.data+0x610): undefined reference to `XML_SetSkippedEntityHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x6c): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x9c): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0xbc): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x11b): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x153): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o):(.text.unlikely+0x173): more undefined references to `XML_ErrorString' follow
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c62): undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c6d): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c78): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c83): undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c8e): undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate_MM'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1c99): undefined reference to `XML_ParserFree'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1ca4): undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1caf): undefined reference to `XML_SetCommentHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cba): undefined reference to `XML_SetDefaultHandlerExpand'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cc5): undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cd0): undefined reference to `XML_SetNamespaceDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cdb): undefined reference to `XML_SetProcessingInstructionHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1ce6): undefined reference to `XML_SetUnknownEncodingHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cf1): undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1cfc): undefined reference to `XML_SetStartDoctypeDeclHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `PyInit_pyexpat.cold.17':
(.text.unlikely+0x1d07): undefined reference to `XML_SetEncoding'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x267b): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x26d5): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x272a): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentByteIndex'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x27ee): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x281c): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentByteIndex'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x2853): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `xmlparse_getattro.cold.20':
(.text.unlikely+0x286d): undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `pyexpat_xmlparser_Parse.cold.21':
(.text.unlikely+0x28f0): undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `call_with_frame.isra.7.cold.24':
(.text.unlikely+0x2a9a): undefined reference to `XML_StopParser'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `get_parse_result.cold.27':
(.text.unlikely+0x2b0a): undefined reference to `XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `call_character_handler.cold.28':
(.text.unlikely+0x2b33): undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `call_character_handler.cold.28':
(.text.unlikely+0x2b95): undefined reference to `XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `set_error.isra.8':
(.text.unlikely+0x2e1a): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentLineNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `set_error.isra.8':
(.text.unlikely+0x2e25): undefined reference to `XML_GetCurrentColumnNumber'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `set_error.isra.8':
(.text.unlikely+0x2e30): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `pyexpat_xmlparser_UseForeignDTD':
(.text.unlikely+0x307f): undefined reference to `XML_UseForeignDTD'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `pyexpat_ErrorString':
(.text.unlikely+0x3b4d): undefined reference to `XML_ErrorString'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `pyexpat_xmlparser_GetBase':
(.text.unlikely+0x414e): undefined reference to `XML_GetBase'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `pyexpat_xmlparser_GetInputContext':
(.text.unlikely+0x449b): undefined reference to `XML_GetInputContext'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `flag_error':
(.text.unlikely+0x31e5): undefined reference to `XML_SetExternalEntityRefHandler'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pyexpat.o): In function `my_ElementDeclHandler':
(.text.unlikely+0x3836): undefined reference to `XML_FreeContentModel'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(posixmodule.o): In function `os_openpty':
(.text.unlikely+0x1447): undefined reference to `openpty'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(posixmodule.o): In function `os_forkpty':
(.text.unlikely+0x1e6e): undefined reference to `forkpty'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(faulthandler.o): In function `faulthandler_thread':
(.text.unlikely+0x618): undefined reference to `pthread_sigmask'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info.part.4':
(.text+0x1662): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info_bases':
(.text+0x16e7): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info_table_bases':
(.text+0x17bb): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__deregister_frame_info_bases':
(.text+0x185e): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__deregister_frame_info_bases':
(.text+0x18e6): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `_Unwind_Find_FDE':
(.text+0x19c6): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_lock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `_Unwind_Find_FDE':
(.text+0x1a16): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `_Unwind_Find_FDE':
(.text+0x1b00): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info.part.4':
(.text+0x1681): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info_bases':
(.text+0x1706): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): In function `__register_frame_info_table_bases':
(.text+0x17da): undefined reference to `pthread_mutex_unlock'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT 2:**
The exact gcc command line:

```
gcc test.c -otest -static $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) -lc -lpthread -lexpat -lz -ldl -lutil -lm
```

**EDIT 3:**
This is the result of `locate`:

```
$ locate libexpat.a libc.a libm.a libz.a libpthread.a libdl.a libutil.a libpython3.5m.a | grep x86_64-
linux-gnu
/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
```

So I should have all static libraries that I need.

This is the *new* error, a bit *shorter* than the first:

```
$ gcc pregex.c -otest -static $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) -lc -lpthread -lexpat -lz -ldl -lutil -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_getgrouplist':
(.text.unlikely+0x3aa6): warning: Using 'getgrouplist' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(posixmodule.o): In function `posix_initgroups':
(.text.unlikely+0x3cc1): warning: Using 'initgroups' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(grpmodule.o): In function `grp_getgrall':
(.text+0x2f5): warning: Using 'getgrent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(grpmodule.o): In function `grp_getgrgid':
(.text+0xe9): warning: Using 'getgrgid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(grpmodule.o): In function `grp_getgrnam':
(.text+0x266): warning: Using 'getgrnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(grpmodule.o): In function `grp_getgrall':
(.text+0x2c9): warning: Using 'setgrent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(grpmodule.o): In function `grp_getgrall.cold.7':
(.text.unlikely+0x15a): warning: Using 'endgrent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pwdmodule.o): In function `pwd_getpwall':
(.text+0x285): warning: Using 'getpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pwdmodule.o): In function `pwd_getpwnam':
(.text+0x1ee): warning: Using 'getpwnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pwdmodule.o): In function `pwd_getpwuid':
(.text+0x9f): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pwdmodule.o): In function `pwd_getpwall':
(.text+0x259): warning: Using 'setpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(pwdmodule.o): In function `pwd_getpwall.cold.6':
(.text.unlikely+0x14d): warning: Using 'endpwent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_getaddrinfo':
(.text+0x167b): warning: Using 'getaddrinfo' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(spwdmodule.o): In function `spwd_getspall':
(.text.unlikely+0x1a6): warning: Using 'getspent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(spwdmodule.o): In function `spwd_getspnam':
(.text.unlikely+0x27b): warning: Using 'getspnam' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(spwdmodule.o): In function `spwd_getspall':
(.text.unlikely+0x1a1): warning: Using 'setspent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(spwdmodule.o): In function `spwd_getspall':
(.text.unlikely+0x1f7): warning: Using 'endspent' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_gethostbyaddr':
(.text+0x2d45): warning: Using 'gethostbyaddr_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_gethostbyname_ex':
(.text.unlikely+0x1ae4): warning: Using 'gethostbyname_r' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_getprotobyname':
(.text.unlikely+0x33ff): warning: Using 'getprotobyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_getservbyname':
(.text.unlikely+0x2263): warning: Using 'getservbyname' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(socketmodule.o): In function `socket_getservbyport':
(.text.unlikely+0x34c3): warning: Using 'getservbyport' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(lowlevellock.o): In function `__lll_lock_wait_private':
/build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:78: multiple definition of `__lll_lock_wait_private'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(libc-lowlevellock.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a(lowlevellock.o): In function `__lll_unlock_wake_private':
/build/glibc-Cl5G7W/glibc-2.23/nptl/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/lowlevellock.S:328: multiple definition of `__lll_unlock_wake_private'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a(libc-lowlevellock.o):(.text+0x30): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(dynload_shlib.o): In function `_PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr':
(.text+0x7c): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT 4:**

Ok, now I'm able to **compile** without errors with this command line:

```
$ gcc -static test.c -otest $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) -lm -lutil -ldl -lz -lexpat -lpthread -lc
```

*I don't know why* but with `-lc` at the end it compile!
The problem is that warnings are still in the output message:

Lots of warnings like this:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.a(dynload_shlib.o): In function `_PyImport_FindSharedFuncptr':
(.text+0x7c): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

Comment: `error: ld returned 1 exit status` isn't the full error message.

Comment: You're right, I edit the question.

Comment: Find out what library those symbols come from, and link it in?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, ok, how chan I find out what library is?

Comment: @GinoC: Documentation, Google, `ldd` on the shared library version

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes I followed the @MikeKinghan answer (used `ldd` to find dependencies but still not work)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see, all of the undefined references in your failed linkage
lie in linked object files that are members of `libpython3.5m.a`, which
is the static version of the python3 library requested in your linkage
commandline by `pkg-config --libs --cflags python3`.

To link a fully static executable (`-static`) when the linkage
includes `libpython3.5m.a`, the linker must also find static (`*.a`) versions of all the
libraries that `libpython3.5m.a` depends upon<sup>1</sup>. The dynamic
(`*.so`) versions of all those dependencies are installed on your system.
That is why:

```
gcc test.c -otest $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3)
```

succeeds, without `-static`. The static versions of those dependencies are
not all installed on your system. Hence all the undefined reference
linkage errors when you add `-static`.

My own system has python3.6, and I see:

```
$ pkg-config --libs python-3.6
-lpython3.6m
```

and:

```
$ locate libpython3.6m.so
/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

The dynamic dependencies of `libpython3.6m.so` are:

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc475af000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fa87cf6e000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fa87cd51000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fa87cb32000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fa87c92e000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fa87c72a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa87c3d4000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa87bff4000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fa87d85a000)
```

We can disregard the first and last ones, which don't look like regular libraries
and indeed aren't<sup>2</sup>. So, I'd conclude that
to satisfy the static dependencies of `libpython3.6a`, I need to install the
static versions of:-

```
libexpat
libz
libpthread
libdl
libutil
libm
libc
```

which will be provided by the dev packages of those libraries. Since my system is 64 bit Ubuntu, I'd then filter those dev packages
by:

```
$ dpkg --search libexpat.a libz.a libpthread.a libdl.a libutil.a libm.a libc.a | grep amd64
libexpat1-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.a
zlib1g-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.a
libc6-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.a
```

and install them with:

```
sudo apt install libexpat1-dev zlib1g-dev libc6-dev
```

You haven't disclosed what your system is, but no doubt you can adapt this
thinking to discover the static dependencies of `libpython3.5m.a`, whatever
your system is.

---

[1] Strictly, all
libraries that the members of `libpython3.5m.a` *that you are linking* depend upon,
but we won't be that pernickity.

[2] The first one is the library's [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO),
not a real file at all. The second one is the linux loader.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 64bit Ubuntu. I had already installed `libexpat1-dev zlib1g-dev libc6-dev`. So I tried to link them: `gcc pregex.c -opregex $(pkg-config --libs --cflags python3) -lc -lpthread -lexpat -lz -ldl -lutil -lm` and this work, but with `-static` do the same as before.

Comment: @GinoC Please post the exact gcc commanline you are using with `-static` (in the body of your question, not in comments).

Comment: Don't you need to add `--static` to the `pkg-config` command too?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't know it had that option option - which beats `ldd` deduction if it works. Adding it
produces dependencies `-lpthread -ldl -lutil -lpython3.5m` as opposed to just `-lpython3.5m` without.
If you see an answer based on this fire away.

Comment: I tried to locate the static version of all libs. I edited my question with result.